# Relating, Joining, or attaching photos to a point layer

Tags: arcmap, aerial-photography, hyperlink, attachments, arcgis-10.8

I have a number of historic aerial images that I am attempting to georeference or at a minimum attached to a point file so I can display them when hyperlinks are activated.

I have a point layer that was created to show where the image was originally taken. This was originally a KML file that I converted and exported for ArcMap. The resulting point shapefile has the name of each photo the point represents. Is there a way for me to add the photos as attachements via their individual names without having to click each one? As you see, i have 4 years and about 100-400 photos for each year.

I do have a corresponding geodatabase from converting the KML but i dont know how to use that to attach the photos.

[image]